# How to find out true dimesion, dpi of picture inside a powerpoint slide without it original JPEG file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I have a big problem here is how to find out the true quality of picture inside  a powerpoint slide and I dont have it original image in JPEG form. Please help me to solve this problem because my client need it to print a big backdrop 6m x 3m.

I appreciate all of your helps and comments.

Your regards,

Comment: Chances are pretty good that **any** image inside powerpoint will be insufficient for a 6x3m area. PPT uses 72/96ppi for everything.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* get the original image from a PowerPoint file:

1. change .pptx to .zip (if it's a .ppt, you're out of luck)
2. unzip folder with your favorite unzipping tool (7zip is my favorite)
3. go into unzipped folder > media > images (or something like that)
4. Here you'll find the original images

But, as noted by [Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3270/scott), even the original image probably won't be good enough to use for a 6x3m billboard. Try getting the original high quality image. Google image search lets you search for an uploaded image, you could try that and buy/download/request the original.

Comment: Normally the ppi of the document shouldn't matter, it is the number of pixels int he image that determines quality. *However*, if Powerpoint downsamples the original image when placing it, then the ppi matters in that  it determines how many pixels to remove.

Comment: Yes, normally Microsoft aplications eat images for breakfast, chew them and turn them into marmalade.